# Is there any pythagorean triple (a,b,c) such that $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod b^{2}$

Tags: number-theory

... or equivalently, is there a $D$, such that $a^2 - Db^2 = 1$

All I managed to do is to use the Euclid's formula

$a = m^2 - n^2,\ b = 2mn$ to test for all $m,n$ between 1 and 3000.

Comment: Hint: Look at $a^2 - b^2 k = 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: @JacobMayle I do not understand: Since $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, there is no problem in modulo $4$. Or Do you mean something else?

Comment: @awllower I just realize my mistake while typing up the solution. Sorry for the bad hint.

Comment: Well, I've gotten some way with it. $m$ and $n$ cannot have the same parity, for one. And if $m = 2^kr$ is the even one (with $r$ odd), then
$$
n^4 \equiv 2^{2k + 1} + 1 \mod(2^{2k + 2})
$$
from the Chinese remainder theorem (and of course vice versa if $n$ is the even one). Then I'm stuck.

Comment: I note that the equations $a^2-Db^2=1$ and $c^2-(D+1)b^2=1$ form a pair of "simultaneous Pell equations"; searching for that phrase might reveal an answer from the literature.

Comment: sweet, I did see the second equation but had no idea how to use it

Comment: Yup, this looks like it follows from an old paper of mine with Gary Walsh in Indagationes Math. from 2000.

Comment: Here is the link for this nice paper: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BW-Indag.pdf. Theorem $1.1$  shows that there are no solutions, because $(D+1)-D=1$, see the last line of Theorem $1.1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is considered good practice not to leave answers buried in comments, I thought it would be good to paste the relevant comments together and take the question off the unanswered list.

We are seeking positive integers $a, b, c, D$ that solve $a^2 - D b^2 = 1$ and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Subtracting the second equation from the first, $b^2(-D-1) = 1 - c^2$ or $c^2 - (D+1)b^2 = 1$. However, the pair of equations

$$a^2 - D b^2 = 1$$ 
$$c^2 - (D+1)b^2 = 1$$

has no pair of solutions, according to the last line of the statement of Theorem 1.1 from [this paper](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BW-Indag.pdf):

- Michael A. Bennett and Gary Walsh, *Simultaneous quadratic equations with few or no solutions*, Indag. Math. (New Series) 11-(1), March 2000, 1-12.