# Find all solution to $a^{2}\equiv -1 \pmod b$ and $b^{2}\equiv -1\pmod a$ (self-answer)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

There was a question here just a moment ago but was deleted by the author. It is to find all solution to $a^{2}\equiv -1 \pmod b$ and $b^{2}\equiv -1 \pmod a$ with $a,b>1$. But I already typed up the solution, and don't want it to go to waste. So I'm posting this with answer.

However, feel free to add your own solution too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: reorganize:

Consider a solution $a,b$. (edit:now we no longer assume that $a<b$)

We have $b|(a^{2}+1)$ so let $c=\frac{a^{2}+1}{b}$. Now $(a^{2}+1)^{2}\equiv 1(\mod a)$. Hence $b^{2}c^{2}\equiv 1(\mod a)$. But $b^{2}\equiv -1(\mod a)$ hence $c^{2}\equiv -1(\mod a)$. Easily see that $a^{2}\equiv -1(\mod c)$. Thus $c,a$ is also a solution to the problem. Note that if $b<a$ then $c>a$ and vice versa.

<s>Use infinite descend we eventually end up having a solution where $c=1$. That is $b=a^{2}+1$. Hence $a^{4}+2a^{2}+1\equiv -1(\mod a)$ which force $1\equiv -1(\mod a)$ so $a=2$ and $b=5$. Note that no matter what $a,b$ we start with at the beginning, we always end up with this value $2,5$.</s>

EDIT: Here is a more rigorous way of doing it:

We define an unique sequence $a_{i}$ where $a_{1}=2,a_{2}=5$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}^{2}+1}{a_{n-1}}$ for $n\geq 2$. From this definition it is immediately obvious that if $a_{n-1}<a_{n}$ then $a_{n}<a_{n+1}$ and so by induction this sequence is strictly increasing.

We have for any $n$ if $a_{n-1},a_{n}$ is a solution, $a_{n},a_{n+1}$ is a solution (remember, if $a,b$ is a solution then $\frac{a^{2}+1}{b},a$ is also a solution; and here we apply $a=a_{n},b=a_{n-1}$). Now we do in fact have $a_{1},a_{2}$ being a solution. Hence by induction, any $a_{i},a_{i+1}$ is a solution.

Assuming that there is a solution not in the form $a_{i},a_{i+1}$. If $a=b$ then immediately we have $0\equiv -1(\mod a)$ forcing $a=b=1$ which not allowed. So there must exist a solution $1<a<b$ not in the sequence with minimum $a+b$. Let $c=\frac{a^{2}+1}{b}$. Then apply the argument above, $c,a$ is a solution with $c<a<b$ so $c+a<a+b$. Hence $c,a$ is in the sequence (due to the minimum assumption) so we have either $c=a_{i-1},a=a_{i}$ or $c=a_{i},a=a_{i-1}$. But $c<a$ so the 2nd possibility is impossible because the sequence is strictly increasing. Hence the 1st possibility must happened. Hence $b=\frac{a^{2}+1}{c}=\frac{a_{i}^{2}+1}{a_{i-1}}=a_{i+1}$ which means $a,b$ is in fact $a_{i},a_{i+1}$ contradicting the assumption that this is not.

Hence all solutions are of the form $a_{i},a_{i+1}$.

Now prove, once again by infinite descend, that $a,b$ are consecutive odd index Fibonacci number then $b^{2}-b(b-a)-a^{2}=1$ (hint: show that $a^{2}-a(b-2a)-(b-2a)^{2}=b^{2}-b(b-a)-a^{2}$ and do infinite descend by replacing $a,b$ with $3a-b,a$.). Using that, we showed that all consecutive odd index Fibonacci number satisfied $b^{2}-b(b-a)-a^{2}=1$. But expand that one out give us $-b^{2}+3ab-a^{2}=1$ which means $b^{2}\equiv -1(\mod a)$ and $a^{2}\equiv -1(\mod b)$. That is consecutive odd index Fibonacci number are always solution.

Let $b_{n}$ be the $(2n+1)$-th Fibonacci number. Then $b_{1}=2=a_{1},b_{2}=5=a_{2}$, and $b_{i}<b_{i+1}$ are always solution.

Now we use induction again. If $b_{n}=a_{n}$ for some $i$, then since $b_{n},b_{n+1}$ is a solution, and all solution is of the form $a_{i},a_{i+1}$ we must have either $b_{n+1}=a_{n-1}$ or $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}$. But $a_{n-1}<a_{n}=b_{n}<b_{n+1}$ hence the first possibility is not possible. Thus $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}$. We already checked the base case. Hence by induction $b_{n}=a_{n}$ for all $n$.

Thus all solutions are consecutive odd index Fibonacci number.

Comment: Why does your infinite descent shows the sequence is unique? It shows that whatever solution we pick, we will finish  in the same state. But that doesn't forbid us from picking an starting point and taking a different route to arrive at $(a,b,c)=(2,5,1)$

Comment: @chubakueno: the idea here is the route is uniquely reversible, and the sequence is just a reversal of it. I have edited the solution to make that part more clear.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your time :)